# Edit rejected because nearly-identical, later edit was done. Why?

Tags: discussion

I've had this happen twice now. I suggested an answer edit to add the spoiler notation to an answer without it. I find later that my edit has been rejected because of a conflict with another edit, and in its place is an edit that was almost identical to mine.

My question is two-fold:

Why is my suggestion rejected and a later (similar) one implemented/approved?

Is this something that should happen on Puzzling.SE?

If I need to split this up into two questions, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

After 2000 rep, you won't have this problem.

Below 2000, you aren't allowed to make edits without approval.  So they go into a queue waiting for one of our fearless moderators to make the decision to approve.  Usually, unless your edit is malicious or moronic, they're approved.  It's a mechanism to keep spammers and vandals coming in and destroying the site.  The very fact that <2000 users are allowed to edit at all, is recognition that you're probably helping out in good faith.

Now, suppose MegaUser10000 comes in and edits the same post you did, before your edit gets approved.  The problem is fixed, and no further edits should be approved.   But you're still waiting in the queue.  The solution is that one of those two edits needs to win, and one needs to lose.  Unfortunately, the one that was actually done wins, and the one stuck in limbo loses.

This is nothing against you or your edits.  It's simply what works.  Answer a few more questions and get the rep up, and you'll start winning the race.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just to note: it is rarely the moderators that approve/reject suggested edits.  It is almost always done via community moderation using the review queues.